# type mismatch errors when upgrading from scala 2.9 to 2.13.2

Tags: scala

I recently revived an old library that was written in scala 2.9, and I created a new scala project using scala 2.13.2

I am getting errors like the following:

```
type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Any]
[error]  required: Seq[Any]
```

Was there a specific change between 2.9 to 2.13.2 that involved not implicitly casting sequences or something that might solve many of these types of compile errors?

I had to add `.toSeq` to many of my function return statements that were vals of Buffer[Any] that needed to be passed as an arguement to a function expected a Sequence.

Comment: `scala.Seq` now alias to `immutable.Seq` instead of `collection.Seq` so you won't be able to pass a mutable buffer as an immutable Seq: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/index.html#Seq[+A]=Seq[A]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite a lot things happened in the last 7+ years (including rewrite of the collections library).

If adding `.toSeq` solves your problem - just go for it.

If you want to know what exactly has changed - try upgrading version-by version: first upgrade to scala-2.10.*, then to 2.11.*, then 2.12.*, then, finally, to 2.13.2.

At each upgrade you'll probably see deprecation warnings. Fix them before upgrading to the next version.

Answer (score 5):

Brave, but perhaps bad form, to disturb the dead. Nevertheless, maybe pass `mutable.Buffer` as `mutable.Seq` instead of `Seq` which is by default `immutable.Seq`. Consider

```
val mb = mutable.Buffer(11, Some(42))
val ms: mutable.Seq[Any] = mb // OK
val is: Seq[Any] = mb         // NOK
```